# Simplifying $(A'+ D) \times [(B \times C) + D']$ in Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

$(A'+ D) \times [(B \times C) + D']$ I can rewrite as $(A' + D) \times (D' + B) \times (D' + C)$.  Is there a way of simplifying to get to the step of $D' + D = 1$ or $D' \times D = 0$ or any other simplifying that I can do?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The original expression can be expanded to:

```
A' B C + A' D' + B C D + D D'
```

`D D'` cancels to `false`. Extracting `B C` we get:

```
A' D' + B C (A' + D)
```

If `A' D'` would be false, either `A` or `D` would be true.
We can therefore assume for the term on the right that `A'` is false.

This results in:

```
A' D'  + B C D
```

If in doubt, write down the truth table to convince yourself.